# Permissão negada ao mover arquivo com move_upload_file em servidor Linux

Tags: php, linux

Estou tentando utilizar o [`move_upload_file`](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) para mover um arquivo enviado pelo usuário para seu destino final:

```php
$pasta = '../../public_html/admin/helpdesk/ticket/uploads/';

if (!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES["img"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        $nome = $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $cod = date('dmyhis') . '-' . $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key];
        $uploadfile = $pasta . basename($cod);
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploadfile)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Porém, está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

Existe uma forma de contornar este problema? Estou passando o caminho relativo do diretório, mas já tentei passar o caminho absoluto e também não deu certo.

Comment: Qual a permissão dessa pasta para o usuario especifico?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Problemas de permissões em servidor Linux

No mundo PHP, existem várias formas de se "rodar" um site, em geral a maioria delas é usando um servidor web conhecido como Apache ou Nginx, ao manipular arquivos, as vezes ocorrem problemas de permissões que não são muito claras, vou tentar desmitificar algumas delas e mostrar o que isso implica em questão de segurança.

#### Tipo de servidor

É comum ver o uso de hospedagens compartilhadas para sistes/sistemas em PHP, devemos nos atentar pois esse tipo de hospedagem geralmente é bem vulnerável se o usuário não tomar as devidas precauções.
Existem também os VPS/Dedicados em que uma instiancia Linux roda isolada, dando assim maior nível de segurança ao sistema/site.

#### 1) Conceito básico de permissões:

No linux, existe um sistema de permissões de arquivos e pastas desenhado para entregar um ambiente seguro compartilhado por mais de um usuário, a grosso modo, no modo de representação numérica, são 3 `bits` que indicam por quem o arquivo pode ser acessado, veja um exemplo:

```
765 arquivo1.txt
644 arquivo2.txt
```

o primeiro dígito, nos mostra qual a permissão do dono, o segundo, qual a permissão do grupo e a terceira, qual a permissão geral (demais usuários).

No primeiro exemplo, temos:

```
7 -> Dono tem permissão 7 (ler, gravar e executar)
6 -> Grupo tem permissão 6 (ler, gravar) porem não pode executar como o dono
5 -> Outros usuários tem permissão 5 (ler e executar) porem não podem alterar o conteúdo.
```

Essa foi uma explicação superficial e pode conter erros, entenda melhor lendo [esse link](http://www.infowester.com/linuxpermissoes.php).

#### 2) Funcionamento de um servidor web no Linux

O servidor web, não roda como `root` ou seja, não tem permissões globais sobre o sistema, em uma instalação padrão, existe um usuário dedicado, geralmente chamado `www-data` e um grupo dedicado, com o mesmo nome.

Quando uma página é solicitada, é esse usuário que lê, interpreta e roda qualquer comando que o script solicitar.

Se a pasta/arquivos do site / sistema pertencem ao usuário `www-data` então a permissão 700 é suficiente para ler, gravar e executar, visto que o dono tem total acesso (7) e os demais usuários não tem acesso algum.

Se o usuário dono da pasta/arquivos do projeto não é o mesmo que o usuário em que o servidor web roda, temos que adicionar permissão nos segundo e terceiro "bit"

digamos que existe um usuário chamado `foo`, e o mesmo pertence ao grupo `www-data`, a pasta do site percente a foo, com grupo www-data

então teríamos que dar permissão 770, para que todos os membros do grupo tenham acesso total ao sistema/arquivos.

## Por quê o 777 funciona, afinal?

> Dando chmod 777 você expôe seus arquivos a qualquer usuário do
> sistema, então em um hospedagem compartilhada, qualquer outro usuário
> será capas de ler seus arquivos, modificar o conteúdo e ainda fazer um
> 'include' via script.

## Conclusões

- Se você usa hospedagem compartilhada, 777 é um erro que você jamais pode comenter.
- Se você usa um servidor dedicado / VPS, você deve configurar os seus arquivos e pastas como sendo propriedade do mesmo usuário em que o servidor web roda, no debian / ubuntu esse usuário é o www-data, mas o mesmo pode ser personalizado / variar em outras distribuições

#### Para trocar o dono de uma pasta e todos os arquivos / pastas internas (recursivamente):

> chown -R usuario:grupo minha_pasta_www

No caso padrão,

> chown -R www-data:www-data minha_pasta_www

---

> Resumindo, 777 nunca!

Answer (score 4):

Fui verificar o diretório e vi que estava com permissão `775`, alterei para `777` e ao tentar salvar o arquivo novamente ocorreu tudo ok.

Comment: vou responder a essa pergunta com o porque de não usar 777

Comment: Não daria pra trocar o usuário em vez de trocar a permissão?