# Unlink para vários arquivos

Tags: php, pdo

estou tentando utilizar o unlink para excluir de um diretório varias imagens não sei o que está acontecendo aparentemente a lógica está correta, meu método é o seguinte:

```
public function deleteImagem($id) {
    $selectDasImagens = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("select nome FROM imagem where id_pagina=:id");
    $selectDasImagens->bindValue(":id", $id);
    $selectDasImagens->execute();
    while ($linha = $selectDasImagens->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo unlink("../uploaded/$linha->nome");
    }
}
```

alguém já passou por isso.

Comment: vc quer apagar vários arquivos? `$linha->nome` já vem com a extensão?

Comment: sim já vem com o nome e sim quero apagar vários arquivos, o interessante é que quando faço sem while ele apaga um arquivo tranquilamente.

Comment: O echo escreve zero(false)?

Comment: isso mesmo, resposta correta.

Comment: Pode ser que não tenha permissão para excluir o arquivo, ou nome não está correto, tente com: `echo unlink("../uploaded/{$linha->nome}");`. Também se consegue excluir passand o caminho completo do arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolvido da seguinte maneira:

primeiro abri o terminal e editei as permissões do diretório: `chmod 777`
depois retirei o echo do método.

```
public function deleteImagem($id) {
$selectDasImagens = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("select nome FROM imagem where id_pagina=:id");
$selectDasImagens->bindValue(":id", $id);
$selectDasImagens->execute();
while ($linha = $selectDasImagens->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    unlink("../uploaded/$linha->nome");
}
```

}

obrigado @rray

Comment: So removeu o echo? ou era permissão o problema?

Comment: dei um chmod 777 no diretório também

Comment: Essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2281/91) talvez ajude a entender melhor o que aconteceu, é um problema relacionado.

Comment: muito obrigado vou ler tudo.