# Erro no upload [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou tentando fazer um registro onde eu tenho `uploads` de imagens e preciso salvar todo este conteúdo em tabelas diferentes. A parte de texto está salvando perfeitamente porém a parte de foto ainda não está salvando.

Segue o código PHP que salva no banco os dados:

```
<?php
// incluindo o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco
include ("../includes/conexao.php");
include ("../includes/suc_validacao.php");
include ("../includes/suc.php");

$cdClie = $_POST['COD_IDENT_CLIEN'];
$titulo = $_POST['TXT_TITUL_PUBLI'];
$status = $_POST['FLG_STATU_PUBLI'];
$resumo = $_POST['TXT_RESMO_PUBLI'];
$msg = $_POST['TXT_DETLH_PUBLI'];
$link = $_POST['TXT_LINKX_URLXX'];
$usurLoga = $_SESSION['UsuarioID'];

$imagem = $_FILES["imagem"];


$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_PUBLICACOES (COD_IDENT_CLIEN, TXT_TITUL_PUBLI, FLG_STATU_PUBLI, FLG_TIPOX_PAGIN, TXT_RESMO_PUBLI, TXT_DETLH_PUBLI, TXT_LINKX_URLXX,  COD_IDULT_ATUAL, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL) VALUES";
$query .=  "('$cdClie','$titulo','$status','012','$resumo','$msg','$link','$usurLoga', now())";

$inserir = mysql_query($query)
or die(error());

$response = array("success" => true);

// Recebeu a imagem
if($imagem != NULL):
    $nomeFinal = time().'.jpg'; 

    // Tenta gravar o arquivo no servidor
    if (move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'], $nomeFinal)): 

        // Pega a imagem
        $tamanhoImg = filesize($nomeFinal); 
        $mysqlImg = addslashes(fread(fopen($nomeFinal, "r"), $tamanhoImg));
        $linkIMG = $_POST['TXT_LINKX_URLXX'];
        $msgImg = $_POST['MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM'];

        // Conecta-se ao BD e tenta gravar
        try{
            $query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tbl_IMAGENS (BLO_CONTE_IMAGM, MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM, TXT_LINKX_URLXX, COD_IDULT_ATUAL, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL ) VALUES ('$mysqlImg', '$msgImg', '$linkIMG', '$usurLoga', now())");
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        // Apaga o arquivo
        unlink($nomeFinal); 
    endif;

else:
    echo"Você não realizou o upload de forma satisfatória."; 
endif;

//fechando a conexao com o banco
mysql_close($conn);

    header("Location: publicacaoPF.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN=$cdClie"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante

?>
```

Código da página aonde envio a imagem:

```
<input id="files" name="imagem" type="file" multiple/>
                <output id="result" />
```

Porém meu projeto tem uma particularidade eu faço o `preview` da imagem e juntamente com o `preview` eu indico mais 2 campos para serem adicionados para cada imagem, um destes campos é a legenda e o *link* caso exista, eu faço isso utilizando o `jquery`.

Segue o código jquery:

```
 <script>

window.onload = function(){

//Check File API support
if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
{
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");

    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

        var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
        var output = document.getElementById("result");

        for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
        {
            var file = files[i];

            //Only pics
            if(!file.type.match('image'))
              continue;

            var picReader = new FileReader();

            picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                var picFile = event.target;

                var div = document.createElement("div");

                div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + picFile.name + "'/> <a href='#' class='remove_pict del'><i class=\"icon-remove\"></i></a> <div class=\"control-group\">                         <label class=\"control-label\" for=\"MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM\">Legenda</label>                          <div class=\"controls\"><input id=\"MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM\" name=\"MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM\" type=\"text\" class=\"input-xlarge\">     </div>                </div>         <div class=\"control-group pull-right linkImg\"><label class=\"control-label\" for=\"TXT_LINKX_URLXX\">Link</label><div class=\"controls\"><input id=\"TXT_LINKX_URLXX\" name=\"TXT_LINKX_URLXX\" type=\"text\" class=\"input-xlarge\">        </div>            </div>";

                output.insertBefore(div,null);   
                div.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
                   div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                });         

            });

             //Read the image
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }                               

    });
}
else
{
    console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
}
}
```

O Erro que está dando é :

> [Fri Jun 26 12:37:24 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(1435311444.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/C_SalvaPublicacaoPF.php
>   on line 35, referer:
>   http://192.168.1.20/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/cadastroPublicacaoPF.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN=12
>       [Fri Jun 26 12:37:24 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]:
>   Unable to move '/tmp/phpMAzIYb' to '1435311444.jpg' in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/C_SalvaPublicacaoPF.php
>   on line 35, referer:
>   http://192.168.1.20/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/cadastroPublicacaoPF.php?P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN=12

Apos alterar algumas coisas no código passou a dar este erro:

> [Fri Jun 26 16:13:51 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Warning:  filesize() >[function.filesize]: stat failed for 1435324431.jpg >in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/C_SalvarPublicacaoPJ.php on >line 31, referer: >http://192.168.1.20/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/cadastroPublicacaoPJ.php?>P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN=17
>   [Fri Jun 26 16:13:51 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Warning:  >fopen(1435324431.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open >stream: No such file or directory in >/opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/C_SalvarPublicacaoPJ.php on line >32, referer: >http://192.168.1.20/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/cadastroPublicacaoPJ.php?>P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN=17
>   [Fri Jun 26 16:13:51 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Warning:  fread() >expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in >/opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/C_SalvarPublicacaoPJ.php on line >32, referer: >http://192.168.1.20/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/cadastroPublicacaoPJ.php?>P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN=17
>   [Fri Jun 26 16:13:51 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Notice:  Undefined >index: MEM_LEGEN_IMAGM in >/opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/C_SalvarPublicacaoPJ.php on line >34, referer: >http://192.168.1.20/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/cadastroPublicacaoPJ.php?>P_COD_IDENT_CLIEN=17

Ele está até salvando porem não pega meus campos de legenda e link.

Comment: Parece ser algo a ver com permissão de pastas no servidor, já pensou em converter a foto para base64 string e salvar ela no banco também?

Comment: Não como faço isto ?

Comment: acho que a resposta desta pergunta pode lhe ser util,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding

Comment: Mais tarde volto aqui e posto uma solução mais completa, estou sem tempo agora

Comment: @Kaizonaro fico esperando.

Comment: Já existe uma resposta aqui no SOpt: [Permissão negada ao mover arquivo com move_upload_file em servidor Linux](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2270/3635)

Answer (score 1):

Voce esta usando lampp. Nesse caso as permissoes pra pasta provavelmente estao configuradas para seu usuario local. Pra voce conseguir mover o objeto, voce tem que dar permissoes para o usuario do apache (nesse caso ele deve ser o owner da pasta, ou pelo menos ter permissoes pra escrever nela).
O usuario padrao do apache eh www-data.
O comando abaixo deve resolver seu problema.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data minha_pasta_www
```

Comment: Irei testar e te falo.

Comment: use também chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp