# mkdir(): Permission denied

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar um diretório pelo PHP no meu servidor local Linux, porém não estou conseguindo. Dá o seguinte erro:

```
mkdir(): Permission denied...
```

Já tentei os seguintes códigos:

```
if(!file_exists($diretorio)){
          mkdir("/../../".$ano,0777,true);
 }
```

e esse também:

```
if(!file_exists($diretorio)){
          mkdir("/../../".$ano);
          chmod("../../".$ano,0777);
 }
```

e por desencargo de consciência:

```
if(!file_exists($diretorio)){
          mkdir("/../../".$ano,0777,true);
          chmod("../../".$ano,0777);
 }
```

mas todos retornam aquele erro. O diretório raiz está com permissão 777. Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: O diretório raiz pode estar com a permissão **777** mas se o diretório que você estiver tentando criar o novo diretório não tiver permissão, não tem como. Exemplo: **/var/www** tem a permissão *777* mas **/var/www/public_html/** não tiver permissão para gravar, você não ira conseguir criar o diretório, mas consegue dentro do diretório **www**.

Comment: Olá wmsouza. Só que eu já tinha dado permissão no diretório onde consta os arquivos e onde quero criar o diretório com o comando `sudo chmod -R 777  'nome do diretorio'` e já confirmei com o comando `ls -l` e a permissão está como 777.

Comment: Então veja essa resposta: [Problemas de permissões em servidor Linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2281/60376).

Comment: Tenta rodar o comando "setenforce 0" no terminal