# Como o "umask" funciona em PHP e quando devemos ou não usa-lo?

Tags: php, segurança, permissões

Estava lendo a [**documentação do `umask`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) e me deparei com isto:

> When PHP is being used as a server module, the umask is restored when each request is finished.
>
> Traduzindo: Quando o PHP esta sendo usado em um modulo de servidor o umask é restaurado quando a requisição termina

Gostaria de saber se isto do `umask` ser restaurado ocorre em qualquer módulo de servidor, como:

- apache2handler
- fast-CGI
- FPM ([FastCGI Process Manager](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php))
- CGI ([Common Gateway Interface](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875))
- IIS ([Internet Information Services](https://www.iis.net))

Ou se é necessário alguma configuração ou *flag* para que o módulo entenda que deve restaurar o umask quando terminar a requisição?

Também gostaria de saber quando e como usa-lo, por exemplo fico imaginando, para uma pasta com uploads do cliente seria interessante limitar as permissões, no entanto noto que algumas pessoas usam `umask` e **outras não**, no momento de um upload, como isto funciona e qual a necessidade técnica e/ou de segurança relacionada a isto?

No momento que estiver movendo um arquivo grande de uma pasta como a `/tmp` usando `move_uploaded_file` para uma outra pasta ao usar `umask` até que a requisição termine de processar a pasta pode estar insegura?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes de entender o `umask`, você deve entender as permissões do *filesystem* dos sistemas *nix, algumas respostas nos posts aqui podem ajudar:

> [Quais são os riscos de usar permissão 777?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169996/70)

> [Permissão negada ao mover arquivo com move_upload_file em servidor Linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2270/70)

Da mesma forma, o `umask` é um conceito que faz sentido em sistemas *nix, é uma camada de compatibilidade do PHP que usa recursos já existentes do *filesystem* (como várias outras *libs* o são, umas para DB, outras para requisições Web, etc) que independe do servidor de páginas.

**Atenção:** quando se escreve um número em PHP (e algumas outras linguagens) prefixado por 0, este é um número OCTAL e não decimal. Permissões *nix são octais por natureza (três bits por dígito).

## Pra que serve?

O nome de certa forma já diz: **U**ser file creation **M**ask. Ele é uma **máscara** que é aplicada em cima das permissões de arquivo.

Ele basicamente **retira** privilégios do processo em execução, negando-os através de uma máscara de bits.

O PHP tem como padrão o `umask` o valor 022, e isso pode ser "afrouxado" se você diminuir este valor.

## Como funciona?

Exemplo do próprio manual do PHP:

```
original 0666 rw-.rw-.rw-
umask    0022 ---.-w-.-w-
final    0644 rw-.r--.r--
```

Vendo em binário pra facilitar:

```
original 000 110 110 110 rw-.rw-.rw-
umask    000 000 010 010 ---.-w-.-w-
final    000 110 100 100 rw-.r--.r--
```

Ou seja, o `umask` negou os bits "2" tanto do `other` quanto do `group`.

Na prática, como o padrão de criação de arquivos no filesystem é `0666` e de diretórios `0777`, o padrão `022` do `umask` do PHP acaba definindo isto como padrão:

- Arquivos criados como `0644`;
- Diretórios criados como `0755.`

Vale notar que o `umask` em si já é "mascarado", ele recebe um `or` com `0777` antes de ser aplicado, então se fizer `umask( 01771 )` valerá na verdade como se tivesse feito `umask ( 0771 )` apenas.

Tem um detalhe importante quando usamos o `umask`, ele retorna o valor atual da máscara, independente de você estar criando uma nova ou só consultando, o que nos leva ao próximo ponto...

## O estado do `umask` ao fim do processo:

No manual temos isto:

> *Quando o PHP está sendo usado como um módulo de servidor, o umask é restaurado ao final de cada requisição.*

Temos que lembrar que quando você roda o PHP como CGI, tem vários processos sendo criados e liberados ao final, e quando roda como módulo, é um "processão" contínuo. Então o que importa não é a "lista" de servidores de páginas usadas, e sim a forma como o PHP é executado para determinar se o `umask` é resetado no final automaticamente ou não.

Resumo: como os casos com que você pode contar com o *reset* do `umask` são muito específicos, e como você não deve depender do estado de um script para a sessão toda, armazene o retorno do primeiro `umask` que fizer e resete sempre o `umask` ao estado padrão no final. Melhor ainda? Não mexa, se não tiver uma razão real para isto. Defina como deve ser na configuração do servidor, e deixe. É uma opção que pode dar muita dor de cabeça se não tiver domínio sobre permisssões *nix, e se tiver, você provavelmente nem precisa desse aviso aqui.

### Manual

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.umask.php